# How to pass arrow pointer into function?

Tags: c

```
struct node {
    int x;
    struct node *next;
};

void allocateMemory(struct node *some_node) {
    some_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}
```

In another function:

```
struct node add(struct node *root, struct node *thisNode, int value)
```

I try to call this:

```
allocateMemory(thisNode->next);
```

I get a runtime error. It does nothing.
Yet when I do the same thing as allocateMemory() in the said function, i.e:

```
thisNode->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

It does what it is supposed to do.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pass the value as a reference or return the value.

Comment: @Austin: I know that that's why suggesting him that pass the value as a reference so that the memory allocated by malloc function get properly allocated to thisNode->next.

Comment: By the way we will happy if you wrote the exact error.

Comment: Your error is thinking that the argument in the function and the variable you passed will be identical. That's not the case: C is strictly pass-by-value, the function only gets a copy of the value you passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to paas **pointer to pointer**.

When you have pointer, then you can *change* value which is that pointer pointing to, and when you want to change the actual pointer then you need go one step deeper.

Also function add shouldn't return value but pointer?

```
struct node {
  int x;
  struct node *next;
};

void allocateMemory(struct node **some_node) {
  *some_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}

struct node* add(struct node *root, struct node *thisNode, int value) {
  allocateMemory(&thisNode->next);
  thisNode->x = value;

  root->next = thisNode;

  return thisNode;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Here in that code :

```
void allocateMemory(struct node *some_node) {
some_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}
```

You can write :

```
void allocateMemory(struct node **some_node) {
*some_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}
```

And while calling :

```
allocateMemory(&thisNode->next);
```

Comment: Here i think it will be allocated memory properly rather than previous code.

Comment: And that is so why? Why did the previous code fail? How does the new code correct the error? Please add such reasoning *to your answer*. As is, this answer is still ... poor.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting.I'll remember that for next time.