# Strange segmentation fault in C when using malloc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I haven't programmed in C for many years, so this might be a no-brainer. When I try to read out some variables x,y,z inside a malloc'd struct, I get a segmentation fault on running the compiled binary. If I uncomment the line: *//v = point3D_initialise(v);* , then it works as expected. It's as if the variable v is not keeping the allocation address. It faults even if I call the function without assert():

```
typedef struct {
    int x, y, z;
} point3D;

point3D *point3D_initialise(point3D *v) {
    v = (point3D*)malloc(sizeof(point3D));
    v->x = v->y = v->z = 0;
    return v;
}

int TEST_setAndReadPoint3D(point3D *v) {
    v = point3D_initialise(v);
    assert(v!=NULL);
    if((v->x == 0) && (v->y == 0) && (v->z == 0))
        return 1;
    else return 0;
}

void TEST_start() {
    point3D *v;
    assert(TEST_setAndReadPoint3D(v));
    //v = point3D_initialise(v);
    printf("x=%d y=%d z=%d\n", v->x, v->y, v->z);
    free(v);
}
```

Comment: The initialize function is weird; you pass in a pointer value, ignore it by overwriting it with `malloc()`, set the members, and return the newly allocated pointer.  When you try using v` in `TEST_start()` without having initialized it with the initialize function, you are invoking undefined behaviour with the references in the `printf()` call.

Comment: By pure chance (maybe not, as it is asked so frequently) almost a duplicate of this hour's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826998/how-to-pass-arrow-pointer-into-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass a pointer by value to your `TEST_setAndReadPoint3D(point3D *v)` and so the malloc return value is assigned to the **copy** of the pointer. Therefore the actual value of the pointer you pass to it has not been altered at all by the function `TEST_setAndReadPoint3D()`. Because it has not been altered it remains uninitialised and so you get segfaults when you try to dereference it.

Try this instead

```
void point3D_initialise(point3D** v) {
    *v = malloc(sizeof(point3D));
    (*v)->x = (*v)->y = (*v)->z = 0;
}

void TEST_start() {
    point3D *v;
    point3D_initialise(&v);
    /* v now has memory allocated to it */
    free(v);
}
```

Comment: I'm an idiot! Yes this is the reason. I was thinking that pointers are automatically referenced for some odd reason. I've done this but I've also made point3D_initialise() return a value with: return *v;. This is because I like to use the function as parameter to another function to test the return value with less code. Thanks a lot.